# Nvm node install checksums do not match because of a forward slash

Tags: checksum, nvm

I'm learning to use nvm to manage node versions, but all my installations fail with the error: checksums do not match.

The only difference is the '\' in the found checksum:

> Computing checksum with shasum -a 256 Checksums do not match:
>   '\0bdd8d1305777cc8cd206129ea494d6c6ce56001868dd80147aff531d6df0729'
>   found,
>   '0bdd8d1305777cc8cd206129ea494d6c6ce56001868dd80147aff531d6df0729'
>   expected. nvm: install v6.9.1 failed!

Answer (score 30):

What's the output of your `nvm ls` command? I was having the same issue, until I discovered my `nvm ls` command was also broken, which led me to [this thread](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1083). Fixing my `~/.bash_profile` to include

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" 
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

and then restarting my terminal solved the problem for me.